# iOS - Should I be calling "weakSelf" in this block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Okay so I might have not fully grasped WHEN I should use `weakSelf` in blocks. I know that it is done to prevent retain cycles and what not, but I heard there are some exceptions to this rule.

In the following code, I check to see if an API call failed due to the login session expiring, and then I attempt to re-authenticate the user and retry the API request that failed because of this issue by calling `[self sendTask:request successCallback:success errorCallback:errorCallback];` in the re-authentication method's success block:

```
/*!
 * @brief sends a request as an NSHTTPURLResponse. This method is private.
 * @param request The request to send.
 * @param success A block to be called if the request is successful.
 * @param error A block to be called if the request fails.
 */
-(void)sendTask:(NSURLRequest*)request successCallback:(void (^)(NSDictionary*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))errorCallback
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        [self parseResponse:response data:data successCallback:success errorCallback:^(NSString *error) {
            //if login session expired and getting "not authenticated" error (status 401)
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
            if (httpResp.statusCode == 401) {
                NSLog(@"NOT AUTHENTICATED THO");
                AuthenticationHelper* auth = [AuthenticationHelper sharedInstance];
                NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                //attempt to re-authenticate the user
                [AuthenticationHelper loginUser:[defaults stringForKey:@"username"] password:[defaults stringForKey:@"password"] successCallback:^(User* u)
                {
                    auth.loggedInUser = u;
                    NSLog(@"RE-AUTHENTICATION BUG FIX SUCCEEDED");
                    //attempt to re-try the request that failed due to
                    [self sendTask:request successCallback:success errorCallback:errorCallback];
                } errorCallback:^(NSString *error) {
                    NSLog(@"RE-AUTHENTICATION BUG FIX FAILED");
                }];
            }
            else {
                errorCallback(error);
            }
        }];
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Is this bad practice in that it can lead to a retain cycle? If so, why? Should I instead be using `[weakSelf sendTask:request successCallback:success errorCallback:errorCallback];` assuming that I do `MyAPIInterface *__weak weakSelf = self;` beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example there would not be a retain cycle because `self` isn't holding a reference to the block.  When the block completes, it will release its hold on `self`, and if that was the last reference, the instance will be deallocated, just as you would expect.

Comment: I don't get how self can hold a reference to a block. Can you please include an example of this in which it would cause a retain cycle? Forgive me, but I just barely started using blocks.

Comment: The same way it can hold a reference to any object -- an instance variable or property.

Comment: @Rafi - consider what might happen if `task` local variable was an instance variable instead: then you possibly have `self` -> `task` -> block -> `self` - which *potentially* produces a troublesome cycle (not all cycles are bad, especially transient ones).

Comment: @CRD I don't really know what you mean but I couldn't find much on Google about transient cycles :/

Comment: @Rafi - just answering the question in your comment. Read -> as "references". If `task` was an instance variable then `self` would reference `task`, which in turn references the block you pass, which in turn references `self`. A transient cycle is simply one which is created and later broken, cycles are only a problem if they don't get broken. HTH

Comment: Ooooh okay. That makes more sense then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A retain cycle is certainly one risk of strong references though I don't think it applies in this case. A strong reference to `self` in these callbacks might extend the life of the `self` object until they complete but it looks like the blocks will be deallocated once called or when requests fail at which point they would release their strong references and the `self` object could be deallocated.

You may however still see unexpected behavior resulting from these strong references. These strong references could keep this object alive until these requests complete. That could result in an object you expected to have been deallocated remaining in memory and changing application state far in the future when the request finishes.

As one possible example; suppose you start one of these requests and then the user signed out and signed into a different account. The request might fail and then be retried using the second user account's credentials. That's probably not the result the user wanted.

Perhaps that's actually not possible in this application but if you use strong references like this you'll need to consider it, and reconsider it every time you change the way the application interacts with this object. That leads to a class being hard or even dangerous to reuse. If you instead make careful use of `strong` and `weak` you can write a class which does not become so coupled to the state of the rest of the application.

Correct use of a weak reference in this case might be a little trickier than you expect. Creating a weakly retained version of `self` is certainly the right first step:

`__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self`

That gives us a `weakSelf` which will be nil if `self` was deallocated *before* the completion block executes however depending on your concurrency model it might be possible for `self` to be deallocated *during* the execution of the completion block. We therefore usually want to create a strong reference as our first operation within the block so that if `self` still exists when the block begins executing it will remain until the block is finished and this strong reference is discarded:

`__strong __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf`

A number of objective-c libraries and projects extract these statements into `weakify` and `strongify` macros which can be helpful.

Comment: Of course, creating that strong reference in the block just brings you back to the first problem of holding onto `self` until the block completes, but now you've added a lovely race condition to the mix.

Comment: There is no way in my app that a user can sign in with another user's credential. When the user logs out voluntarily, then the defaults are cleared and the global `loggedInUser` is set to nil.

Comment: Retaining `self` during the execution of the block is not a problem. Retain cycles are an issue when the block captures a strong reference to `self` and retains it even when not executing. I also see no race condition here; `strongSelf` will exist or be nil for the duration of the block.